How long does it take to transfer between Don Mueang and Suvarnabhumi airports in Bangkok?
I’m planning to visit Thailand at the end of October 2024. My flight lands at Don Mueang (DMK) at 4.15 a.m. I have a another flight booked at Suvarnabhumi (BKK) to Phuket at 7.00 a.m. Can someone tell me whether the time is enough for me to transfer between two airports including all the immigration work? Does the domestic checkin counter close 40 mins before departure?

Thanks for the information guys.After considering everything, i decided to book a different flight that leaves from DMK itself. Thanks again.

This is extremely risky. I would not book this.
You need to clear immigration in DMK, wait for your bags and clear customs. Then head outside and grab a taxi or try the shuttle. If you are lucky you can get one quickly and early enough to head out before the traffic gets really bad. See also: https://thaiest.com/blog/dmk-to-bkk-don-muang-airport-to-suvarnabhumi-airport
If all the stars line up and you are extremely lucky, you can make it but I give it a less than 50% chance. Keep in mind that if you miss the flight you are a no-show and may have to buy a new same day ticket on the spot. This can get very expensive even on a route that’s typically cheap.

Does the domestic checkin counter close 40 mins before departure?

That depends on the airline. Check their website.

+1. Just to run the numbers, OP has 2:45 to make the connection if their flight is on time, and it takes 60 min to drive the 50 km from DMK to BKK on a good day (and Bangkok is justly famous for terrible traffic). If OP needs to check in 40 min before, this leaves them with 1 hr to pass through immigration, collect bags, pass customs. Doable if the stars line up, but very little buffer if they don't.

Don't neglect the walking within both airports.  This can be significant.

@lambshaanxy 40 min at 5am.

@badjohn ~3 min at BKK from taxi to check-in. ~3 min at DMK from immigration to taxi.

In the last few days, I have travelled from central Bangkok to both airports using public transport.  I did not go directly between them.  One day, I helped my wife to Suvarnabhumi and the next day I went to Don Muang train station (next to the airport).  The BTS system does not go to either airport, you need to change to an airport rail link.  This requires a separate ticket.  So, you will need 3 tickets and 4 trains (1 change within the BTS system).
I don't think that this could work for you.
In general, I would recommend the trains for getting to either airport.  A taxi might occasionally win in a race but it is a big gamble.  The trains are more reliable and less stressful.
As others have said, a taxi might work if you are lucky.  Google Maps estimates 55 minutes for the drive and it does not go through central Bangkok.  The walking within both airports is significant and you cannot afford a single mistake.  Do you know your way around both airports?
I would not recommend attempting this.  Change one flight by a day.  Spend a day in Bangkok; it's a nice place and not very expensive.
I am not sure when trains begin and end.  Very early or very late, the taxi is probably preferable.  However, during the day  (even weekends), I would prefer the trains.  I might be biased because I have spent too much of my life in Bangkok traffic jams.

"In general, I would recommend the trains for getting to either airport. " not at 5am.

@FranckDernoncourt A good point but I have already admitted that it won't work for the OP.  It could be useful for someone else.

Got it. I definitely share your Bangkok traffic jam PTSD.

All current answers and comments are incorrect.
My estimate:

Flight lands at Don Mueang (DMK) at 4.15 a.m. (though I guess you meant the scheduled arrival time to the gate)
Time when entering the taxi at DMK: 5:15 am (there is no traffic jam before 6 am, so the taxi ride is ~40 min).
Time when exiting the taxi at BKK: 6:00 am
Time when checking-in at BKK: 6:05 a.m. (which is about 10 minutes before the check-in closes, depending on the airline).

So you'll be fine assuming the flight to DMK isn't delayed, or that you don't have immigration or custom issues.

So you're saying the OP will be fine because they have a whole 10 minutes of buffer if everything goes perfectly?  I admire your optimism.

@lambshaanxy My estimates are already conservative. >90% likelihood to make it imho. Can run to save a few minutes, tip taxi if it's a slow driver, etc.

If everything goes well.  If OP is flying on flight FD131 (JAI-DMK, arr 04:15 AM), it's been delayed 30-45 min 4 out of the last 7 flights this week: https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/AIQ131/history

@lambshaanxy Yes I wrote "assuming the flight to DMK isn't delayed". No clue which flight OP is taking. The question is "How long does it take to transfer between Don Mueang and Suvarnabhumi airports in Bangkok?"
